# Please tell me what this silverlight warning message means

Tags: c#, silverlight

Please tell me what this silverlight warning message means.

> Warning    1   For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse
>           and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.

What do I do to fix this issue?

Comment: _'To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method._'

Comment: The problem is likely that the poster has - like many programmers dealing with XML - no clue what he really does and the abbreviation "DTD" does not tell him anything. As a result, the error messages does not mean anything to him eitehr.

Comment: @TomTom: It doesn't need to mean anything (although it would be useful to learn) because the latter explanation of _how to enable DTD_ (regardless of what it is) is explicit.

Comment: I fully agree there. Asking here how to get around this is a failed intelligence test - failure to follow simple written instructions. He asks also what it means, though.

Answer (score 2):

You ought to simply follow the instructions given in the error message.

It would be useful if you posted the relevant code, but as it stands, the error message seems rather precise:

> *To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on
>   XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create
>   method.*

If you can provide more contextual information (preferably related code and scenario) then we may be able to provide more specific help.